# Android - ListView - Context menu not working

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I have a `ListFragment` where I register the context menu using `registerForContextMenu()` and I override `onCreateContextMenu()`. 
The issue is that `onCreateContextMenu()` is never called when I long press any item.

Here's some code:

```
public class List_F extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onActivityCreated(arg0);

        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        setListAdapter(...);
        setListShown(false);

        // launch cursor loader
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int i = item.getItemId();
        if (i == R.id.menu_item_delete) {
            delete(info.id);
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why?

I also tried

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener()
```

and it's not even called.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Found the culprit!

I was setting a `OnClickListener` on the view in the `Adapter`.

This was probably eating the long press event.

I changed the `OnClickListener` in each view to a `OnItemClickListener` on the `ListView`